# No Video on HTC Vive Cosmos Elite

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, steam

I've got a HTC Vive Cosmos Elite and am trying to use it with Steam VR.

It shows up as connected and when screen mirroring is on I can see on my PC screen that the unit is being tracked correctly but there's no video on the HMD.

I'm using up-to-date `5.6.19-2-MANJARO`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the Cosmos is Linux compatible. See [redit-link](https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualreality_linux/comments/gi6ejl/vive_cosmos/) . I'm also kinda pissed because I thought we were past this point of hardware compatibility.

Comment: Just because the manufacturer doesn't support it, doesn't mean we can't get it to work...

Comment: Well, let me (and the community) know if you get it to work.

Comment: Have you had any luck making the Cosmos work in Linux, specifically UNITY-game engine?

Comment: Nothing yet, I'm waiting for the new version of SteamVR (that supports XMR) to be released and then I'll see if I can get something working

Comment: Any update on the cosmos support? (am going to return mine)